# read kubernetes secrets mounted as volume in application.properties spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, kubernetes-secrets

I created kubenertes secret

```
echo -n 'myusername' > username.txt
echo -n 'pa55word' > password.txt
kubectl create secret generic esb-database-secret-vol --from-file=username.txt --from-file=password.txt
```

I created pod manifest as

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: data-api-0.0.1.jar
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
    name: esb-data-api
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    resources: {}
    volumeMounts:
    - name: esb-secret-vol
      mountPath: "/etc/confidential"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: esb-secret-vol
    secret:
      secretName: esb-database-secret-vol
```

I verified that secrets now available in pod /etc/confidential folder

How does these values be available in application.properties so that I can get DB connection

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://mycompany.com;databaseName=My_DB
# need to read from /etc/confidential/username.txt
spring.datasource.username=??????
# need to read from /etc/confidential/password.txt  
spring.datasource.password=??????
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Comment: you got any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. Provide the data already in properly written properties files
2. Use an init container to use the secret data and create properties files using a shell script

The first approach would look like

```
echo 'spring.datasource.username=myusername' >> app.properties
echo 'spring.datasource.password=pa55word' >> app.properties
kubectl create secret generic esb-database-secret-vol --from-file=app.properties
```

You would later mount the secret as `application.properties` in the container.